# Rspecを実行すると、Rails environment is running in production mode!とエラーが出てしまう

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

現在ポートフォリオ (Rails-api,React) を作成中で、本番環境herokuまでデプロイが終わりました。
以前書いたRspecを実行し問題ないことを確認したあと、CI/CDを導入していこうと思っていたところだったのですが、Rspecが以前は出なかったエラーが出てしまい、ググっても解決できなかったので、投稿させていただきます。

以下のコマンドを実行後、エラーが表示されてしまう。

```
docker-compose run api bundle exec rspec
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Creating cooklog_api_run ... done

An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/favorite_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?

NameError:
  uninitialized constant Rails
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/models/favorite_spec.rb:1:in `require'
# ./spec/models/favorite_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

以下helperをrequireしているテストは全て同じように表示されます。

```
No examples found.

Finished in 0.00015 seconds (files took 0.42682 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 8 errors occurred outside of examples
```

後述する rails_helper.rb の7行目の以下記述がエラーとして出てきているようです。

```
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
```

本番環境としてtestを実行してしまっているのでしょうか？

#### 試したこと

`rails console` で現在の環境を確認

```
[1] pry(main)> Rails.env
=> "development"
```

Dockerを使わず、ローカルの環境でも `bundle exec rspec` を実行したところ、エラー内容は変わりませんでした。

原因がわからず、困惑しております。
お知恵をいただけるとありがたいです。
最後までお読みいただき、ありがとうございます。

---

rails_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require "spec_helper"
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
# require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)
#エラーが出るためコメントアウト
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require "rspec/rails"
# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

require "capybara/rspec"

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
# run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
# in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
# run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
# end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with the --pattern
# option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
#
# The following line is provided for convenience purposes. It has the downside
# of increasing the boot-up time by auto-requiring all files in the support
# directory. Alternatively, in the individual `*_spec.rb` files, manually
# require only the support files necessary.
#
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec", "support", "**", "*.rb")].sort.each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations and applies them before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove these lines.
begin
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
rescue ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError => e
  puts e.to_s.strip
  exit 1
end
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # You can uncomment this line to turn off ActiveRecord support entirely.
  # config.use_active_record = false

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
  config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request
  # config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :system
  config.include LoginHelpers
  config.include JsonApiHelpers
  # テストケース共通の事前処理
  config.before(:each) do

    # let(:rspec_session) で指定された値を セッションの初期値とします
    session = defined?(rspec_session) ? rspec_session : {}

    # destroyメソッドを実行してもエラーにならないようにします（必要であれば）
    session.class_eval { def destroy; nil; end }

    # 追記 実行後のセッションを取得できるようにする
    config.add_setting(:session, :default => session)

    # 変更 sessionメソッドをRSpec.configuration.sessionで上書き
    allow_any_instance_of(ActionDispatch::Request).to receive(:session).and_return(RSpec.configuration.session)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

再度`docker-compose run api rails generate rspec:install`を実行したところ、
テストが動くようになりました。

しかし、まだrspecでjsonを使えるようにする設定がおかしな挙動するようになったので
別のエラーとして対応してきます。
閲覧いただきありがとうございました。